# How to obtain bounding box for the current viewport?

Tags: rendering

I need to generate a quick preview image in Material Preview mode to be used outside of Blender. For this, Viewport Render Image with orthographic mode seems to work well. However, I also have to know the bounding box coordinates for the viewport at the moment of rendering. Is there a way to get this data, does not matter if it is via the UI or Python API.

Ideally I would also like to crop generated preview, but it looks like Render Region option only works for proper rendering with camera, and it seems to be ignored in viewport rendering mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will find a visible viewport and print 3D coordinates of the corners in that viewport:

```py
from bpy import context as C
from bpy_extras.view3d_utils import region_2d_to_location_3d

area = next(a for a in C.screen.areas if a.type == 'VIEW_3D')
region = next(r for r in area.regions if r.type == 'WINDOW')
r3d = area.spaces[0].region_3d

_2d = lambda x, y: region_2d_to_location_3d(region, r3d, (x, y), (0,0,0))

print(_2d(0, 0))
print(_2d(0, region.height))
print(_2d(region.width, 0))
print(_2d(region.width, region.height))
```